# Removing duplicates based on single column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am tryng to remove the Duplicate based on first column using this below formula but when i am trying to add the `group by Col1` its is throwing an error.

Then i read that we have to `sum` `count` or `average` function before applying the `gropu by` but there is not such column where i can apply one of them

Your help will be much appreciated to remove the Duplicate based on Single Column that is `ColA`

```
=query(ARRAYFORMULA(clean(PROPER(TRIM({{Sheet1!A1:E,{"Employee";"Sheet1"&Sheet1!Z2:Z}}; {Sheet2!A2:E,"Sheet2"&Sheet2!Z2:Z}})))), "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 where Col1 is not null",1)
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74855618/edit) your question and show a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vlookup()` and `unique()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      unique(Sheet1!A1:A), 
      Sheet1!A1:E, 
      column(Sheet1!A1:E), 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```